# Jmeter - to record and playback

Tags: jmeter

I used Jmeter to record clicking on 5 different pages and check a checkbox and save it. I unchecked those checkboxes manually and ran the Jmeter. The testplan ran fine, but the checkboxes are still unchecked. Wont the Jmeter do it? The checked checkboxes are actually inputs to another test case and so I thought I can use Jmeter to do it instead of writing code to check the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter acts on **protocol** level, it doesn't actually "check" the boxes or "type"anything into input fields, it sends the relevant HTTP Requests and measures server response time.

Well-formed HTTP request will "tell" the server that the boxes are checked so from server's point of view it should be different from the real browser, however you may need to perform some extra JMeter configuration, i.e.:

- Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan to add cookies support to your test
- Sometimes (in fact very often) you need to handle dynamic parameters which are being used for security reasons to ensure user's origin or track page state or whatever by extracting them from previous responses and adding the extracted values to the next request. The process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)
- Before putting your server under the load check your script integrity by running JMeter in GUI mode with 1 Virtual user having [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener enabled - this way you will be able to see requests and responses details to ensure your script is doing what it is supposed to be doing.